# specify gradle properties file as command line argument to gradlew

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I am working on a project where there is a different gradle.properties file for each environment. The process seems to be to rename gradle.properties.env (for example) to gradle.properties as required.

I am new to Gradle so possibly this is the wrong approach more broadly, but for now, is there a way to tell ./gradlew to use a specific file as its gradle.properties e.g.

```
./gradlew --propertiesfile=gradle.properties.env
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to put the environment-specific property file in the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` folder (defaulting to `$USER_HOME/.gradle`). Configurations in this location take priority over the ones in the project folder.

Another option is to supply the individual properties as system properties or environment variables.

Comment: The gradle.properties files contain nothing but environment variables - I assume Gradle can't be passed in a config file so what is the best way to handle different environment variables for different environments?

Comment: Seems like something like https://discuss.gradle.org/t/best-practices-for-build-configurations-dev-prod/6975/2 could work:
`def envScript = file("gradle/$environment-env.gradle")
if (!envScript.exists()) {
  throw new GradleException("Unknown environment: $environment")
}
apply from: envScript`